# How can I destroy this jQuery control binding?

Tags: jquery

I am using http://uniformjs.com for my html controls. 
We can apply this using code below.

```
$("select").uniform();
```

How can I destroy this control binding?

I was expecting `$("select").uniform('destroy');` like other jQuery plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
When cloning, it was imperative that $.uniform.restore('select'); was included, but
    var cloneCntr = 1; // Global unique counter
                //var gid = '';
          $('#cloneButton1').click(function() {
                cloneCntr++; // Increment counter
                var $clonedDiv = $(".ivsites:last").clone(true);

                            $("*", $clonedDiv).add($clonedDiv).each(function() {
                            if (this.id) {
                                this.id = this.id.substring(0, this.id.length - 1) + cloneCntr;
                             }
                            if (this.name) {
                                this.name = this.name + cloneCntr;
                            }                   
                        });


                            $clonedDiv.appendTo('#navcontainer ul:last');       
                            $.uniform.restore('select');
                            $("select").uniform();

            });
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
$.uniform.restore('select');
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
delete $.fn.pluginName;
```

Answer (score -1):

See if this works for you:

```
$('select').replaceWith($('select').clone(false));
```